# How do sudden spikes affect hidden Markov models

Tags: r, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have some data that has two sudden spikes (almost like extreme masses or Dirac delta functions) within my time series data and I was wondering if that is a problem when building hidden Markov models.  Here is a plot of my data to illustrate the point:

[image]

I am trying to use HMM to estimate the number of latent states in the data (using the RHmm package) but I keep running into NaN problems when I get data sets with these spikes.  Does anyone have an explanation for why this is or how I can alleviate this problem?

If it helps, here is some R code I wrote that illustrates the point as well:

```
library(RHmm)

y = c(100,rnorm(10000))

#This code works fine
HMMFit(y[-1],nStates=2)

#This code doesn't
HMMFit(y,nStates=2)
```

And the output:

```
> y = c(100,rnorm(10000))
> 
> #This code works fine
> HMMFit(y[-1],nStates=2)

Call:
----
HMMFit(obs = y[-1], nStates = 2)

Model:
------
2 states HMM with univariate gaussian distribution

Baum-Welch algorithm status:
----------------------------
Number of iterations : 21
Last relative variation of LLH function: 0.000001

Estimation:
-----------

Initial probabilities:
       Pi 1      Pi 2
  0.4468508 0.5531492

Transition matrix:
          State 1   State 2
State 1 0.7607666 0.2392334
State 2 0.5074063 0.4925937

Conditionnal distribution parameters:

Distribution parameters:
               mean       var
State 1  0.03591381 1.1009758
State 2 -0.04717922 0.7706617

Log-likelihood: -14171.31
BIC criterium: 28407.1
AIC criterium: 28356.62
>
>
>
>
> #This code doesn't
> HMMFit(y,nStates=2)

Call:
----
HMMFit(obs = y, nStates = 2)

Model:
------
2 states HMM with univariate gaussian distribution

Baum-Welch algorithm status:
----------------------------

NO CONVERGENCE AFTER 1 ITERATIONS

PROBLEM IN BAUM-WELCH'S ALGORITHM

Last Estimation:
----------------

Initial probabilities:
  Pi 1 Pi 2
   NaN  NaN

Transition matrix:
        State 1 State 2
State 1     NaN     NaN
State 2     NaN     NaN

Conditionnal distribution parameters:

Distribution parameters:
        mean var
State 1  NaN NaN
State 2  NaN NaN

Log-likelihood: NaN
BIC criterium: NaN
AIC criterium: NaN
```

Comment: Not your question, but some typos in the code somewhere: "conditionnal" should be "conditional", "criterium" should be "criterion" (work is of Greek origin, not Latin). Also, I vote for "Gaussian".

Comment: In above, "work" should be "word".

Comment: Haha, yeah I guess the authors of the package didn't take the time to do spell checking.